# Laptop gets hot when in GRUB menu

Tags: grub2

I have Dell XPS 9575 2-in-1 and it gets quite hot with fans working intensively. My laptop gets very hot and loud when:

1. during boot menu (GRUB) I leave GRUB menu opened for 5+ minutes -- happens always all the time
2. when booted into Manjaro -- happens once or twice per hour

Important: the described above happens all the time only when it's connected to outlet. If I disconnect the outlet, the laptop stops being hot and fans stop in a minute.

I think this is definitely not normal. How can I figure out what's causing the problem?

Comment: In GRUB that's normal. In Linux - run `top` or `sudo powertop` in console.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because that particular Dell model is known for heating and power management issues. In fact the XPS line has been known for having multiple hw issues. The cause of the problem is well established if you use Google, this is not a Unix question.

Comment: I rephrased my question for clarity.